# (true + false) > 2 + true; Why does this return false?

Tags: javascript, boolean

Im studying javascript and can't figure it out why this line returns false:

```
(true + false) > 2 + true
```

Comment: Does this code have any practical use?

Comment: @RobertHarvey today I wanted to almost chain jQuery's hasClass(), I went with this: `$($0).hasClass("button") + $($0).hasClass("red") == 2` to try something purely for a bit fun hehe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`true` equals 1. `false` equals 0.

So your expression is equivalent to:

```
(1 + 0) > 2 + 1
```

which reduces to

```
1 > 3
```

which is false!

Answer (score 2):

That's because your code evaluates to :

```
1 + 0 > 2 + 1
```

Which is equivalent to :

```
1 > 3
```

This is due to the way that `Javascript` is evaluated and interpreted by the Javascript engine when you are using arithmetic operators on some types, such as booleans, which are implicitely converted, in this case, to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is called type coercion; You're using two boolean values in an arithmetic operation which is not feasible unless the interpreter converts them into numbers first.

true --> 1
false --> 0

Try it yourself; type +true and you will get 1;

Answer (score -1):

true = 1 and false = 0

so expression would be like

```
(1 + 0) > 2 + 1;
(1) > 3;
```

which is false;

Comment: The [accepted answer from almost a decade ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21784706/19068) goes through the same steps and explains them more clearly. Please don't add answers to answered questions if they don't significantly improve on existing answers.